# Get the handle of a Matrix block

Tags: matrix

I am performing the following query, which returns me an array of matrix blocks:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::MatrixBlock);
$criteria->relatedTo = array(someCoolId, anotherCoolId);
$relatedStories = $criteria->find();
```

When looping through this array, I was wondering if it was possible to access the handle of the matrix block that I am currently in. Reason being is I would like to retrieve this as a string, and perform some type of work on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the `handle` of an element that has different types (`entries`, `matrix`) with `getType()->handle` for example:

```
$handle = $entry->getType()->handle
```

In your case

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::MatrixBlock);
$criteria->relatedTo = array(someCoolId, anotherCoolId);
$relatedStories = $criteria->find();
foreach ($relatedStories as $block){
    $handle = $block->getType()->handle;
    switch ($handle){
        case 'foo':
            break;
    }
}
```

Edit:

Not sure what you mean exactly so I'll just insert some random code parts until something is correct.

```
// get the parent element -> the owner of that block.
$parent = $block->getOwner()

// get the field that relates both elements
$field = craft()->fields->getFieldById($block->fieldId);
$fieldHandle = $field->handle;
```

Comment: Now that's what's up.

Comment: Actually, I needed to deselect this as the selected answer. What I actually meant in my question, was, can I get the handle of the actual top level Matrix field, not the handle of every block in the matrix.

Comment: For example, Say I have a field called, "coolStuff" which is a matrix, and that matrix is one of the matrixes included in the array sent back to me from my query. Can I get the handle of "coolStuff" when looping through this array?